# while refreshing the page there is delaying in showing the contents in nuxt 3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a project in Nuxt3 and I can't pinpoint the reason why the contents are displaying after some time like 2-3 sec delay and I don't want that.

Does anyone know why it is happening, is it Nuxt problem or Vue component problem while rendering?

Comment: dev environments are not a great indication of final performance.  try building your app and running the production version and see if its still a problem.

Comment: @yoduh there are some vue warn in console is it because of that